# Invoke-Command runs OK as Administrator, but not as current user

Tags: powershell, 32bit-64bit, credentials, remote-server, access-denied

The following code works fine when I run it in the PowerShell ISE as Administrator (i.e. I start the PS ISE as Admin)

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {[IntPtr]::Size}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {[IntPtr]::Size} -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $Credential

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {[IntPtr]::Size} -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $Credential -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32
```

I get the expected responses of

```
8
8
4
```

This tells me that WinRM is correctly configured and running, and that my $Credential is correctly setup. However, when I try running the same in the PS ISE as a user (with or without Admin rights) I get the following errors for the second and third commands

```
[<ComputerName>] Connecting to remote server <ComputerName> failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (<ComputerName>:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I will be substituting the ScriptBlock code with something more substantive, that needs to run in 32 bit mode because of dependencies on 32 bit DLLs, and the ability for users to run some of the code in 64 bit mode and other parts in 32 bit mode is important.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the credential the same as your login?

Comment: @Jimbo - Yes it is, which is why this is so confusing. Also, the same cerdential in either Admin or User mode, and it works fine in Admin mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSRemoting uses an endpoint, or session configuration, on the remote computer. You're obviously aware of this, as your third command includes the ConfigurationName parameter. These endpoints -- Microsoft.PowerShell, Microsoft.PowerShell32, etc. -- include permissions on them that indicate who can connect to them.

Go to your remote computer (your local computer in this instance), and run Get-PSSessionConfiguration and take a look at the Permission property. You'll quickly realize that you administrative access is a requirement. This is by design; it's a good thing!

Your options are to one, edit the endpoint(s) and add your user(s), two, grant required access to your user (whether that be Admin or potentially Remote Management Users access), three, use a credential object when you run Invoke-Command, passing the credentials, or four, creating your own endpoint with the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks @TommyMaynard - Since the $credential is the same whether the script is run in the Admin or the User ISE, and it works in the Admin ISE - I am assuming (a) the user has been added (Using the currently logged in user credentials anyway), (b) the user has the required access, since it runs in the Admin ISE (c) the -Credential parameter is used in commands 2 & 3. So the confusion persists! How does one go about suggestion #4? btw - Get-PSSessionConfig works only in the Admin ISE - how to or possible to run in user mode?

Comment: For suggestion #4 did you mean to use : Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.Powershell32 -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI. I did do that, but the effect of it does not seem to be persistent!? When I go back to the configuration, my Execute permission seems to have gone away.

Comment: Please ignore previous comment about persistence. For suggestion #4 did you mean to use : Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.Powershell32 -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI. I did do that as well, and all users have FullControl.

Comment: OK - So using Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.Powershell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI and Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.Powershell32 -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI and granting Execute permission to the Users group resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm glad you determined the best option for you and your environment. Using Set-PSSessionConfiguration would've been my first suggestion: "...edit the endpoint(s) and add your user(s)." 

The fourth option, creating additional endpoints, is the most involved/difficult of the options. It involved creating your own endpoint/session configuration. It begins with New-PSSessionConfigurationFile. I did a write up about constrained endpoints way back that discusses creating your own custom endpoints. You can read more about it on tommymaynard.com; search for constrained endpoints.